# How to parent objects to a rigged mesh?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, parent

Hello a blender newbie here. I'm trying to animate a character. I have just successfully finished rigging my character but realised that there are some further objects that should follow the rigged mesh. In object mode, I tried to make the secondary objects children of the rigged character, but when I returned to Pose mode these objects dont follow the character when I change the pose. I know i can join the parts together but its essential that the secondary objects stay there own object. Is it possible to parent objects to a rigged mesh? Im sorry for if i was unclear, if necessary i can try to explain it better or add a .blend file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to add an Empty centered on the object.
Parent the armature to that. (armature = child)  Take the secondary object and also parent that to the empty.  Move the model by animating the empty, not the model.  Posing or animating the primary model's parts shouldn't affect the 2ndry one either.

Comment: Thanks for replying maybe this works for other people, but i found out that using the weight paint mode to paint the secondary objects works perfectly too, still thanks for replying :)